# Find sum of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Alright so this series is infinite and arithmetic. $n=1$

$$\frac{1}{n(n+2)} = \frac{1}{1\cdot3} + \frac{1}{2\cdot4} + \frac{1}{3\cdot5} + \cdots$$

I basically have no idea on how to solve this... any tips? But I know the answer should be $ \dfrac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Do you know how $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$ is determined?

Comment: See [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: it should be a telescopic series and should be done by partial fractions, if that helps?

Comment: @logicc, are you answering your own question?

Comment: It is _not_ an arithmetic sequence.  That would mean that the amount added to $1/(1\cdot3)$ to get $1/(2\cdot4)$ would be the same as the amound added to $1/(2\cdot4)$ to get $1/(3\cdot5)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{1}{n(n+2)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Decompose $\frac{1}{n(n+2)}$ into two fractions in order to get a telescoping series.